# How to get data via Ajax in an HTML binding of knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

There is a DIV-container with an HTML binding and I need to get data from the server via Ajax.get request and display that data inside the contaner.

Something like this:

```
<div data-bind="html: ko.computed( ... get data via ajax here ... )">
</div>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JavaScript code you can define an observable object, and update its value in http response:

```
var data=ko.observable();

$.get(url).then(function(response){
    data(response);
});
```

In the html file you can bind the data to element:

```
<div data-bind="html: data">
</div>
```

Comment: York Chen, Is it possible to put all the needed code inside the DIV element, without modifying javascript file?

Comment: Hi Zurab, I don't think there is a way to do that. If you only do not want to modify js file, you can write js code in your html file, wrapped in a <script> tag.